# Jquery: Redirect Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://localhost:8080/ChecktToken",
    data: {"token": ($.cookie("uid")) },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function() {


    },
    error: function(data) {
        location.href =('login.html')   
    },
});
```

The above Ajax call is used for redirecting the user to the login page if he is trying to access any other pages before actually logging into an application.
This works completely OK, but it takes about 2 seconds to redirect to the login page.

So for example if I try to access `http://localhost:8080/index.html` prior to logging in I will be able to see that page for 2 seconds before actually being redirected.
Is `location.href =('login.html')` the best method for redirection or is there something better I could do?

Looking for advices.

Comment: which page you have written this function?

Comment: That is the time taken for your ajax call to respond - if you check the network tab in chrome, you should be able to see the time taken while waiting for the decision.

My suggestion would be to use a loading spinner - which would overlay the contents and hide it once the AJAX calls are successfully completed.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao All the pages except the `login.html` page.

Comment: That's the best way, but this is the time taken for your ajax call to respond!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 second delay in redirecting page is due to Ajax call waiting for response from server. These 2 seconds may increase if network of server slows down. To prevent page load you have hide page till you get the response or error. You can do that using beforeSend call back in ajax.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://localhost:8080/ChecktToken",
    data: {"token": ($.cookie("uid")) },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
       //Hide page till you get the response. You can use element Id which holds entire body.
       $(body).hide();
    },
    success: function() {
      $(body).show();
    },
   error: function(data) {
      location.href =('login.html')   
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) This is a much more effective way of doing it.